# Find out navigation target in WkWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I need to find out the navigation target for an URL that is going to be loaded in WkWebView. The web application inside the WkWebView is configurable to open a specific link in either an iframe or in a new window (popup with `target="_blank"`).

Several answers on the internet make it easy to find out if the link is going to be opened in a new frame. The following check will do it. The callback comes from `WKNavigationDelegate`:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
    if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
        // new frame
    }
    return nil
}
```

Issue: I do not know whether it was caused by `target="_blank"` or an iframe. Both methods will cause the condition above to be true.

Edit: I can't decide by the navigation URL because it won't change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function to intercept the url which is clicked and then write your frame logic:

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
print(\(webView.URL!.absoluteString))
}
```

Comment: Sadly, the URL won't change. It is the same.